# Obtaining Clients List (Active Clients) for a multicasting daemon in C/C++ (either Gstreamer API or C sockets)

Tags: c++, c, sockets, gstreamer, multicast

**OSes: LINUX (both Redhat Enterprise and Ubuntu LTS)**

I am current working with Gstreamer Pipeline for multicasting video data to various clients. My pipeline looks as follows. `rtspsrc location=rtsp://<ip>:<port>/<location>.sdp latency=0 ! udpsink host=225.1.1.1 auto-multicast=true port=5678 sync=false async=false` . As one can see I have a multicast group **225.1.1.1** and port **5678**. Given this information, is a way to obtain a list of the currently connected/ active clients (IP addresses and other attributes) if any either through (1) Gstreamer API (2) Berkeley Unix Sockets in C/C++?

Think of this as a mini sniffing tool (not as complicated as tshark, ngrep, pcap etc). I could probably use a combination of bash/Python scripts and tshark with some filters. But I prefer C C++ code if possible (non-root execution would be great!).

Comment: since UDP is stateless/ connection-less, there is no active connection acknowledgement. Hence it seems that a TCP based mechanism may have to be used.

Answer (score 0):

In a typical `RTSP` Streaming scenario, the client would invoke a `SETUP` command prior to a `PLAY` in which the type of data and client ports are available. `SETUP` is usually invoked after a `DESCRIBE` response has been received i.e. client knows the properties of the source and proceeds with the setup of connection. So, SETUP could be a good place to know more about the clients.

Comment: Remember that the situation is the above pipeline is a multicast broadcaster. At source it connects to a single stream. In this example the src end stream input is RTSP but I could replace this with MJPEG stream. The multicasting happens at the sink end of this pipeline (not src). Thus rtsp specific related solution is futile as it is not generic and may not apply for mjpeg source. In any case this solution seems irrelevant to the issue described above.

Comment: For any data transmission, won't `listen` be more helpful to know more about the incoming connections?

Comment: How will I apply the same to my case? what about socket file descriptor info that lies in the gstreamer pipeline code?

Comment: @Ganesh This is multicast. There is no listen(), and no incoming connections.

Comment: @EJP thanks, you are right. The connection would be over `UDP` with `SOCK_DGRAM`.

Answer (score 0):

The GStreamer Pipeline API/protocol may supply a way: UDP multicast itself certainly does not. All you can know is whether or not there are any clients at all, and you have to write some raw sockets code to do that (IGMP protocol).